# Exception while trying to use jersey and jaxb

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

The following code:

```
@POST
@Path("/previous-status/{current}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPreviousStepStatus(@PathParam("current") JAXBElement<WorkflowStep> step) {
    WorkflowStep wfStep = step.getValue();
    return DBAccessor.getPrevStepStatus(wfStep);
}
```

Produces the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Rest Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If it is commented I don't get the exception. The currently used libraries in the web application are:

```
asm-3.1.jar
jersey-core-1.11.jar
jersey-server-1.11.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
jersey-servlet-1.11.jar
activation.jar (part of jaxb distribution)
jaxb-api.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.2.jar
```

The reason I have included the last 5 libraries in the list is this article from [developer works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/#resources)

Furthermore from the tomcat start up log I see the following:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String restful.SilverLine.getPreviousStepStatus(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String restful.SilverLine.getPreviousStepStatus(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement), annotated with POST of resource, class restful.SilverLine, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

Any ideas will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PathParameter and entity is something different, try following:

```
@POST
@Path("/previous-status/{order}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPreviousStepStatus(@PathParam("order") int order, JAXBElement<WorkflowStep> step) {

    ...

    WorkflowStep wfStep = step.getValue();
    return DBAccessor.getPrevStepStatus(wfStep);
}
```

in this case, you can do requests like POST http://host/previous-status/10 and put whatever you want into entity.

You had xml in path param (which is part of URL), which is not possible to use. Your request would look like POST http://host/previous-status/<some-xml><foo>bar</foo></some-xml > , which is .. not good idea and not supported.

You should take a look at Jersey user guide: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/ , topics like path param injection, accessing entity and working with XML are well covered there.